# Building Command to Append Selected Text to End of File (w/Tab Completion)

Tags: files, auto-complete-mode

**Problem:** I'm trying to write a command that takes the selected text and appends it the end of a file of my choice.

There also needs to be a tab completion (or autocompletion) element to the command, in the sense that the command should be able to autocomplete to files that are nested somewhere within the directory `/tab/completion/directory`.

**Example:** Suppose there is a file `/tab/completion/directory/nested/file.md`, and I select text in my buffer and run `M-x append-to-file`, then I should be able to `M-x append-to-file file.md<TAB>` for it to autocomplete to `M-x /tab/completion/directory/nested/file.md`. After running this command, the selected text should be sent to end of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question, append-to-file already appends the selected region to a file you specify:

```
append-to-file is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘files.el’.

(append-to-file START END FILENAME)

Append the contents of the region to the end of file FILENAME.
```

As for completion, I recommend you strongly consider the ivy/swiper package.

https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper

http://oremacs.com/swiper/

If you are trying to find the file without knowing the path then you probably want to look at projectile-find-file. Then write a function that calls append-to-file and projectile to fill in the filename.

Comment: I already have projectile and helm. I'm totally new to elisp. Can you demonstrate (or at least sketch) how to call append-to-file and projectile to fill in the filename?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `ido` see [introduction here](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/introduction-to-ido-mode), then all code you have to write is this:

```
(defun my-append-to-file (file)
    (interactive "Ffilename")
    (write-region (mark) (point) file 'append))
```

You could also use `M-x write-region` directly.

Comment: This works to append text to the end of a file, but it doesn't seem to have autocomplete features for nested filenames.

Comment: The autocompletion is done by `ido`. If you use `ido` you have autocompletion on every operation in minibuffer, which uses filenames or buffernames. This is really nice. Please have a look at the Introduction link I provided in my answer.